# Terraform aws_ssm_parameter null/empty with ignore_changes

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, ssm

I have a Terraform config that looks like this:

```
resource "random_string" "foo" {
  length = 31
  special = false
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "bar" {
  name = "baz"
  type = "SecureString"
  value = random_string.foo.result
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [value]
  }
}
```

The idea is that on the first `terraform apply` the `bar` resource will be stored in `baz` in SSM based on the value of `foo`, and then on subsequent calls to `apply` I'll be able to reference `aws_ssm_parameter.bar.value`, however what I see is that it works on the first run, stores the newly created random value, and then on subsequent runs `aws_ssm_parameter.bar.value` is empty.

If I create a `aws_ssm_parameter` data source that can pull the value correctly, but it doesn't work on the first `apply` when it doesn't exist yet. How can I modify this config so I can get the value stored in `baz` in SSM and work for creating the value in the same config?

Comment: Have you tried storing the value in your state?

Comment: The odd thing is that when I pull state I actually see the value stored in there, but then when it gets used it's empty/null.

Comment: Does the IAM user/role you are running Terraform as have access to use the `kms:Decrypt` action with the KMS key that this `SecureString` parameter is encrypted with? There's information on what is required [in the SSM documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/services-parameter-store.html#parameter-store-policies).

Comment: I checked and the role I'm using does have `kms:Decrypt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I forgot about this question, but turns out I did figure out the problem.

The issue was that I was creating the ssm parameter inside a module that was being used in another module. The problem was because I didn't output anything related to this parameter, so it seemed to get dropped from state by Terraform on subsequent replans after it was created. Exposing it as output on the module fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry not enough karma to comment)

To fix the chicken-egg problem, you could add `depends_on = [aws_ssm_parameter.bar]` to a data resource, but this introduces some awkwardness (especially if you need to call `destroy` often in your workflow). It's not particularly recommended (see [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html#data-resource-dependencies)).

It doesn't really make sense that it's returning empty, though, so I wonder if you've hit a different bug. Does the value *actually* get posted to SSM (i.e. can you see it when you run `aws ssm get-paramter ...`)?

Edit- I just tested your example code above with:

```
output "bar" {
  value = aws_ssm_parameter.bar.value
}
```

and it seems to work fine. Maybe you need to update tf or plugins?

Comment: I thought about trying to add `depends_on` but didn't seem like it would help, but I can try. It does get posted to SSM correctly, the main issue is that on subsequent runs the value of the `bar` resource is empty while I can pull the value from an SSM data source for `baz`.

Comment: I should add that I tried this and it didn't help, unfortunately.